# Bash regex to rename set of files

Tags: linux, regex, rename

I have to rename a set of files, using the `rename` command (with a regular expression). 
After some tries, I'm not able to find an expression that gets the expected result.

I've got a file pattern like that:

```
prefix_some_name_other.txt
```

All files begin with the "`prefix_`" string and end with "`_other.txt`",
and the *some_name* part can consist of multiple (alphanumeric) words
separated by underscores. 
So it's possible to have:

```
prefix_one_name_other.txt
prefix_this_is_my_name_1_this1_other.txt
```

I need to rename the filenames like these:

```
other_one-name_datetime
other_this-is-my-name-1-this1_datetime
```

In other words:

- Need to delete "`prefix`" (leaving the underscore)
- "`other`" token goes to the beginning of the file name
- In *some_name*, convert underscore (_) to dash (-)
- The underscore at the end of the filename (after *some_name*) must remain
- Need to delete the `.txt` extension, replaced by *datetime*.

What I've tried:

```
rename 's/fw_([a-z]+)_(\d)_(\w+\d)_(\w+)\.txt/$4_$1-$2-$3_'$datahora'/' *.txt
```

`$datahora` has *datetime* value (tested). This works as expected with

```
prefix_name_1_gnt1_other.txt
```

but not with

```
prefix_other_name_2_gnt2_other.txt
```

Where did I go wrong? How else could I accomplish that?

I have hanged my mind, since for now I'm not able to find a regex that works for all file names that I've got. I know, that the first element in the string is always the `prefix` part, and the last element is then `other.txt` part of the string. So is possible to split string into an array, and get the items that I need to build the new name. In fact, something like that.

```
datahora="20140718-080000"
arrfiles=( *.txt )
for curfile in ${arrfiles[*]}
do
    arrparts=( ${curfile//_/ } )
    numitems=${#arrparts[*]}
    newname=""
    for (( c=1; c<numitems-1; c++ ))
    do
        newname+="${arrparts[c]}-"
    done
    newname=${newname%-}
    arrparts[numitems-1]=${arrparts[numitems-1]/.txt/}
    newname="${arrparts[numitems-1]}_${newname}_$datahora"
    echo "$curfile pasa a $newname"
    mv ${curfile} ${newname}
done
```

After done in this way, I have give another try to @peterph suggestion, and finally done with some rename regex combinations. Somethink like that:

```
rename 's/_/-/g' *.txt
rename 's/^fw-(.*)-([^-]*)(\.txt)/$2.$1$3/' *.txt
rename 's/(\w+)\.(.*)(\.txt)/$1_$2_'$datahora'/' *.txt
```

I'm not sure what is the best aproach. In my opinion, the regex variant seems more elegant, but I need three rename operations (access three times to disk) to do the work, while the `array`variant only writes once onto disk.

¿What do you think about those two solutions?...

Thank's again.

Comment: Might be better suited for the [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: May I move this question?

Answer (score 2):

Unless your `rename` can accept multiple substitution commands *and* the root of the file name (`some_name`) may contain more than one underscore, you have to do this in two steps: a) replacing underscores with dashes and b) (re)moving chunks around in the file names.

The regular expressions you are looking for can be for example:

```
rename 's/_/-/g' *.txt
rename 's/^prefix-(.*)-([^-]*).txt$/$2_$1_'$DATETIME'/' *txt
```

The first one does the underscore to dash translations while the latter does the swapping of root and suffix and appends the contents of the `DATETIME` environment variable to the names. And omits the prefix and extension, of course.

The `[^-]*` part matches any string not containing a dash. In case the suffix is always the same you can put it there verbatim as is the case with the prefix (and vice versa - if the prefix may vary, use `^[^-]*-` to match it as any string not containing a dash located between the beginning of the file name and (thus) the first dash).

If your `rename` supports multiple commands, just concatenate them:

```
rename 's/_/-/g;s/^prefix-(.*)-([^-]*).txt$/$2_$1_'$DATETIME'/' *txt
```

Comment: Thank you very mucho peter, but seem's it doesn't work as spected. I get this conversion:  
`other-this-is-1-name-20140717-093458`  
When I'm looking for:  
`other_this-is-1-name_20140717-093458`

Note the underscore after `other`and before datetime.

Comment: With a little changes into the regex @peterph suggest, and combine with other regex to make the work. See my new edit for further details.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough - I've updated the answer. You just need to change the separators around the file name root: just replace the dashes around `$2` with underscores in the second regexp.